# Is there anything like UserControl in Visual C++/CLR

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I try to make a menu in the left of my program.. The goal is that **with the press of the button** it changes the content of the program... I saw that **C#** has UserControl that seems like doing my job but in **C++** there isn't something similar.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Managed C++ should be able to use just about any .NET type that C# can.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 Well thats what i believed but there isnt any option for that.